# Ubuntu 14.04 - sensors with bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, gpu, temperature, sensors

I installed ubuntu last week and since I have two graphic cards in my notebook (nvidia geforce 5400 and intel integrated) I installed bumblebee to switch between them. The only problem is that since I installed bumblebee my graphic cards sensors do not show up in lm-sensors. I was expecting to have two gpu temperatures when I type sensors, one for each graphic card, and even executing sensors-detect nothing seems to happen. This is what appears when I run `sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +54.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
temp2:        +54.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +54.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +56.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +53.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Hope someone can help me, my notebook keeps turning off and Im pretty sure the integrated graphic card is overheating. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not a bumblebee user but my understanding is that bumblebee is using the nvidia proprietary driver which implies that lmsensors will no more handle the temperature of the nvidia gpu. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/utils/bumblebee-nvidia, it depends on the NVidia proprietary driver.

If I am right, you can read the temperature of the NVidia chip with the command 'nvidia-smi' or a GUI like 'psensor' (to install it: sudo apt-get install psensor).